# Can I use 'not' as a discrete dirac delta function in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

Can I use `not` as a discrete dirac delta function in Matlab?

The definition for the discrete dirac delta function is that
for argument 0 it returns 1, and otherwise it returns 0.
But that is exactly what the `not` function does in Matlab also!

Do you see any problems if I use `not` instead of writing my own
dirac delta function? I am aware that Matlab has a `dirac`
function, but that one is the continuous version - it returns infinity
for 0 instead of 1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it's OK, but note that the output of `not` is an array of `logical`s:

Example:

```
a = [0, 1, pi]
b = not(a)
c = double(b)
whos
```

Output:

```
a =

   0.00000   1.00000   3.14159

b =

   1   0   0

c =

   1   0   0

Variables in the current scope:

   Attr Name        Size                     Bytes  Class
   ==== ====        ====                     =====  ===== 
        a           1x3                         24  double
        b           1x3                          3  logical
        c           1x3                         24  double

Total is 9 elements using 51 bytes
```

So if the inputs are `double`s, I would define the discrete Dirac delta function this way:

```
ddirac = @(x) double(not(x));
```

or

```
function y = ddelta(x)
y = double(not(x));
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning then that you can convert a `logical` expression to a `double` value in Matlab by placing a `+` sign in front it (it is often, but not always, done automatically, so it is probably good practice).

Comment: Or just `double(~x)`.

Answer (score 6):

For clarity, I would define

```
diracdelta = @not;
```

to make it clear in your code that you mean to be using the dirac delta function, rather than doing logical negation. When you revisit your code in six months time, you'll thank me for the extra clarity.

Comment: +1: It's probably better to define `diracdelta = @(x)+(~x)` according to [jazzbassrob's recommendation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18362486/can-i-use-not-as-a-discrete-dirac-delta-function-in-matlab#comment26960119_18362701) to force the result to be of type `double`. This can make a difference, for instance when indexing.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a quick aside, if you try to evaluate this (or any dirac function) for numbers with large amount of significant figures, it will not evaluate properly owing to the (im)precision of floating point numbers.

```
x = [-2e-6:0.5e-6:2e-6]
y = (x - 0.5e-6)
~y
```

However, the element of x that appears to be zero will not be true zero.

```
y(6) =    1.0588e-22
```

Therefore, I propose a function that will return 1 if x is really, really close to zero; closer than the precision of the floating point number:

```
 epsdirac = @(x) double(abs(x) < eps)
```